# eclipse UI: sort or filter jars and class folders

Tags: java, eclipse

In the `Eclipse` UI, under "Java Build Path", is there a way to sort or filter the jars and class folders?  When there are many entries (e.g. > 20), it is very hard to actually see if a certain jar/folder is among the list of entries.  See an example screenshot below

[image]

Comment: It seems to be a Maven project. In the _Maven POM Editor_, in the _Dependency Hierarchy_ tab is the filter you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for howlger's reminder.  Indeed the `Maven POM Editor` of `Eclipse` provides a very nice UI, including filtering of artifacts, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Even better, I think it is a much better alternative to the old way that I know of -- running the `dependency:tree` goal of `Maven`

The UI makes this check so much more easier.  I am show a use case below just to motivate more people to try out the editor (to use it, open a `pom.xml` file, and then click on `Dependency Hierarchy`)

In the screenshot, you can see that at one point I have more than one sets of jetty artifacts (9.2.14 vs 6.1.26) and that was causing my system to fail.  With the UI it is so much more easy to spot the conflict.

[image: Maven POM Editor showing all the artifacts related to "jetty"]